# What labs/companies provide comparative genomic analysis?

Tags: human-genetics

I’m looking for labs/companies that provide comparative genomic analysis between two different species, AND do so for the “paying” public.  I am looking to test a hypothesis regarding genetic expression and would appreciate any direction.  Thanks!

Comment: What's your starting material and your budget? e.g. animal tissue and $x.xx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, tissue, and a budget of appx. $5000.00. But I honestly have no idea how much labs might charge.

Comment: Well first figure out what kind of work you need done. If you have tissue, you'll need extractions done. If you're doing NGS you also need the library prepared and a sequencer ran. Then multiply that cost by the number of samples. At Duke's NGS core, for example, RNA-seq with library prep on their MiSeq instrument for 10 samples will cost you around 15,000. Extractions will probably be extra. I've seen companies push QIAcube extractions for around $65 a sample.

Comment: @CKM  Understood. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlham Institute have the expertise for this work.  They primarily work in public-funded research but they carried out private-sector work in the past.